# Confidence interval for logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, confidence-interval

After logistic regression analysis using gtsummary package in R, I got p-value, odds ratio and 95% confidence interval as below

[image]

With the p-value>0.05, however, 95% CI did not include 1.

When changed the confidence interval to 99%, I got the result as below

[image]

What did I wrong with my analysis?
What should I do to get the correct result?

**** I update the result of summary(result)
[image: Call:]

I also update my raw data, consisting of 507 columns and 2 rows (MI as independent variable and Y as outcome)

MI  <- scan(textConnection('
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0'))

Y <- scan(textConnection('
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0'))

Comment: Sorry, but I find it impossible to tell why this seemingly contradictory behaviour is happening without being able to replicate your analysis.

Comment: Your 99% results seem broadly plausible given your 95% results (more confidence requires a wider interval).   But (even accounting for using log-odds and rounding) the estimates do not seem to be in the middle of the confidence intervals

Comment: @Henry this is expected. The "OR" is exponentiated from the original scale, because reporting a log-odds ratio, the actual coefficient - makes no sense.

Comment: @DANA can you update your post with the output from `summary(my.model)`?

Comment: @AdamO If the central odds-ratio estimate is $b$ within a confidence interval $[a,c]$  then I would not be surprised to see $\frac{c}{b}=\frac{b}{a}$ or $\log(c)-\log(b)=\log(b)-\log(a)$ though affected by rounding.  But here it seems $\log(c)-\log(b)\le \log(0.725)-\log(0.145)\approx 1.61$ $< 2.26\approx \log(0.145)-\log(0.015) \le \log(b)-\log(a)$

Comment: I updated the output from summary(result) and raw data, thank you :)

Comment: Why do you think there is any contradiction here?  I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `gtsummary` is using the Wald test based on a normal approximation to get the p-value (the same as `summary.glm` would use), while its getting the confidence interval from `confint` which uses the profile likelihood to generate the confidence interval.

These two things won't necessarily coincide.  The profile based confidence interval is more reliable.

You can generate the confidence interval implied by the Wald test using `emmeans`,

```
> emmeans::emmeans(mod1, pairwise~MI, type="response", infer=c(TRUE, TRUE))$contrasts

 contrast  odds.ratio   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL null z.ratio p.value
 MI0 / MI1       6.62 6.77 Inf      0.89      49.2    1   1.846  0.0649
```

or the p-value from a likelihood ratio test using

```
> drop1(mod1, test = "LRT")
Single term deletions

Model:
Y ~ MI
       Df Deviance    AIC    LRT Pr(>Chi)  
<none>      227.07 231.07                  
MI      1   233.32 235.32 6.2572  0.01237 *
```

Note from your cross-tab of Y vs MI there is only one value with Y=1 and MI=1

```
   MI
Y     0   1
  0 390  86
  1  30   1
```

Which may explain the larger than usual discrepancy between the two tests.

Comment: The easiest way to obtain the Wald confidence interval for a `glm` is to specify `confint.default(myfit)`. In general, I don't rely on packages to do all the thinking for me, but in this case the `emmeans` output seems to agree between CI and p-value (although the contrast is opposite)